# "null" as discriminator in discriminated union

Tags: typescript, null, discriminated-union

I'd like to use a discriminated union with `null` as its discriminator:

```
type Result<T> = { result: T; error: null } | { result: null; error: string }
```

So if the `register()` function returns a `Result`, I could do this:

```
const { error, result: user } = await register(fields)
if (error) return typedjson({ fields, fieldErrors: { email: error } })
// Everything went ok: user is available
```

But this doesn't work because TypeScript doesn't seem to be using `null` as a discriminator for the union:
[image]

Which is confusing because https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27695 seems to have added `null` as a discriminator.

#### My temporary workaround:

Use boolean as the discriminator:

```
type Result<T> = { invalid: false; result: T; error: null } | { invalid: true; result: null; error: string }
```

but this adds one more (unnecessary) variable to the destructuring statement:

```
const { invalid, error, result: user } = await register(fields)
if (invalid) return typedjson({ fields, fieldErrors: { email: error } })
```

Comment: I can't yet upgrade to v5, so I'm using: `"typescript": "^4.9.5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because empty string is falsy.

you'll be fine with `if (error === null) ...` to decriminate the union.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFQHxQLxQG8oAnBFYALigwG4oJjiB7YqgOxWSgF8oAfQiTKp2nOg2aso8YMQCWbAOY8AUGoBmiNgGNgcpmyjqmTABSs4SVGhnylWAJSEVUV1DnrzAOgks8ufA5kZCcCFzcI4i9SK2Bw1wB6BIiAPQB%20eJ56ZHhoMIjI6OE4iKTUjIjuFW4gA)

Comment: I went with `if (error !== null)` though so I could use the Return Early pattern.